# The meaning of "rallies and reserves"

Tags: meaning

> It’s one of those twin cases of mine,’ he explained. ‘One of ’em’s
> back again. Recurrence—in the scar—after eighteen months.’
>
> ‘That means?’ said Harries.
>
> ‘With that particular kind of trouble—three—five months’
> reprieve—perhaps. Then final recurrence. The other one’s all right, so
> far, they say.’
>
> ‘She would be. This one is One-twenty-Eight,’ said Loftie.
>
> ‘How do you make that out?’
>
> Frost had entered and was going through Vaughan’s indent with
> Ackerman.
>
> ‘Frost, what is One-twenty-Eight’s timing?’ Loftie interposed.
>
> ‘One-two-Eight, sir? Flood from midnight till four a.m.—ebb from four
> to eight p.m. . . Yes, sir, I can make the table-linen all right, and
> the jugs. But we’re short on bath-towels just now.’
>
> ‘Would it prove anything if she lasted out nine months?’ Harries
> picked up the thread of talk with Vaughan.
>
> ‘No. There are **rallies and reserves**.’
>
> ‘A full year?’
>
> ‘I should accept that. But I know who wouldn’t.’ Vaughan gave a great
> name.

This is from "Unprofessional" by Rudyard Kipling.
https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/unprofessional.htm

I don't understand the meaning of
rallies and reserves

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Comment: I have to say that the story is fairly incomprehensible to me (and I like Kipling’s short stories). It sounds as though written after Kipling and Conan Doyle had gone on a binge together. But I suspect that “reserves” is a typographical error for “reverses.”

Comment: Do you know what a rally is? Do you know what a reserve is? Have you looked them up in a dictionary like [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com)? If you have and are still confused about the meanings, please edit your question to tell us where you looked, what you found, and what you're still unsure about

Comment: It seems highly probable that, in context, this is a misprint for “reverses.” Looking up the meaning of “reserves” is not going to help the OP.

Comment: More context? The OP provides over one hundred words of text and a citation to the complete story?

Comment: Ok, so rallies means a sick person gets better. A doctor might say: This patient has rallied. Reserves could be reverses instead, as Jeff said. In that case, it would be: some patients rally and other experience a reverse. In other words, become more sick. Don't get better.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff and Lambie! your are comments are very helpful for me!